# Excel: Handling numbers as text and VLOOKUP

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet used to lookup descriptions, etc. on ICD 9 and ICD 10 codes. Since these codes can be prefixed with zeroes (0), they must be handled as text. Here's the problem I've having. I have the following cell macro:

```
=IF($B9="","",IF($J9=TRUE,"",VLOOKUP($B9,'ICD Codes'!$A$2:$F$35848,6,FALSE)))
```

Cell B9 is defined as text, and I did .NumberFormat = "@" just in case. In the ICD Codes table, I have column A define as text, and again, I did .NumberFormat = "@". Anyway, there seems to be something wrong with the initial load of the ICD Codes table where the lookup for some cells is coming back with "#N/A". If I go into the table, find the code, set my cursor in the cell and hit enter, something is changed where all of a sudden it works. I've tried going through each cell in the column with VBA code, taking the value, doing a CSTR and then putting it back, and that seems to have no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have space, line breaks or some other non printable character in the data.  Try in an empty column `=TRIM(CLEAN(A1))` where A1 is your first cell of data, and copy down the column.  The copy and paste just the values.

Comment: You could also try `=IF($B9="","",IF($J9=TRUE,"",VLOOKUP("*" & $B9 & "*",'ICD Codes'!$A$2:$F$35848,6,FALSE)))` as you formula

Comment: VLOOKUP with "*" didn't work, I got a "#VALUE!" result. As for TRIM/CLEAN, I'm not sure how to copy/paste just the value, but we're talking almost 14,000 values and I don't know which ones have the problem without testing each individual code (not all of them have it), so this wouldn't be a viable solution.

Comment: It happens when switching between text and general/number formatting. Always grinds my gears. If you format all the relevant cells as text **BEFORE** entering data, it will work perfectly. As you say, if you try to change the formatting after data has been entered, you need to put it into edit mode(F2 or double-click) and 'modify the cell.

Comment: Yeah, what makes it uglier is that the input I was given had all the values enclosed in single quotes ('1973', etc.), so it was handled as text when I copied/pasted, but removing the single quotes has done something funky. I might just have to bite the bullet and write something in VBA to take the original input a reload to see if that works.

Comment: Insert a new column in front of column A. Format it as text, then use VBA to load up your 14K cells into it with the cStr function..

Comment: CSTR was one of the first things I tried. I ended up going back to my original input and writing VBA to read it, strip off the single quotes, do a regular search (no VLOOKUP), set NumberFormat to "@" and then put the value back in. That solved the problem. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. Grrr. Back to the drawing board in the morning...

Comment: Hey MacroMarc, I ended up doing a variant of what you suggested. I wasn't confident about Cstr, but since ICD9 and ICD10 codes can be entered with or without a "." and the column with the "." wasn't affected, I created a new column, as you suggested, and removed the "." from the other column, making sure to set it to numeric before inserting the value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per MacroMarc's comment, I ended up creating a new column and made sure to set the number format to text prior to putting in any values. Fortunately I had a second column that I could convert since I really didn't trust the problem column at this point.

Comment: If I could, I'd give MacroMarc credit for the right answer. Once I'd already stripped off the single quotes, this was the only solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim lastRow, i As Long
Dim ICDStg As String

lastRow = Cells.Find("*",SearchOrder:=xlByRows,earchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    ICDStg = Cells(i, "B").Text
    Cells(i, "B").NumberFormat = "@"
    Cells(i, "B").Value = ICDStg
Next i
```

Comment: No, that won't work, I tried that and even did a Cstr. Apparently once you've put something numeric in a column prior to setting the number format, no matter how hard you try Excel won't budge. In my case, it was originally text (enclosed in single quotes), but removing the single quotes caused some of the values to go numeric, but not consistently. I ended up temporarily creating a new column and populating it.

Comment: Replace the following line in the code:
Cells(i, "B").Value = ICDStg

with:
Cells(i, "B").Value = Replace(ICDStg,"'","")

It should work, give it a try.

Comment: Following code is tested and its working fine on ICD codes enclosed in single quotes. this code copy the ICD code from column B to D and removes the single quotes and convert it in text. ICD remains same even if you press F2 or edit it.


Sub CovertICD()
Dim lastRow, i As Long
Dim ICDStg As String

lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    ICDStg = Cells(i, "B").Text
    Cells(i, "D").NumberFormat = "@"
    Cells(i, "D").Value = Replace(ICDStg, "'", "")
Next i
End Sub

Comment: It would've worked, if I hadn't already removed the single quotes after copy/pasting into the sheet (which created the problem). It was really funky after that. Some of the values in the column were handled as pure text, others were not. No rhyme nor reason to it. So ultimately, my only choice was to either reload or what I did below with creating a new column and converting the ICD codes with "." to without. Thanks, though.